# Remove Windows Media Player without removing the whole Desktop Experience

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-media-player

I needed a Windows picture viewer on Windows Server 2012 R2 and had to install the complete Desktop Experience feature, which includes Windows Media Player. I do not need it, because I plan to use another, better, one.

I would like just not to use it, but Windows regularly restores file handlers, so that Windows Media Player pops up from time to time.

How to remove Windows Media Player without removing the whole Desktop Experience?

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell running as administrator.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WindowsMediaPlayer
```

The desktop experience feature will still be enabled